# set dynamic global variable in codeigniter based on user id

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I deal with this kind of problem where I need a variable from my database (with a specific user id) to be set globally before any page is loaded?

The code I have put in my constants.php file is the following:

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB');
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->where('org_id', $this->auth_user_id)
    ->select('bg_color')
    ->get('local_settings');
$colorResult = $query->row();

defined('LOCAL_BG_COLOR')                       OR define('LOCAL_BG_COLOR', $colorResult->bg_color);
```

This just returns me an HTTP error 500, I am guessing it is beacuse auth_user_id is unknown in the constants file. 
I tried putting it in the config.php file, which also gives me the same error.

Comment: Could you put it in the __constructor of a MY_Controller so it's always loaded no matter what controller you end up executing? Or if it's one variable, set it in a cookie.

Comment: Thank you! placing it in "'class MY_Controller extends Auth_Controller" did the trick !